# Carb Backloading

Tags: diet, nutrition, carbohydrate, ketogenic-diet

A friend of mine has sent me a book by John Kiefer on Carb Backloading that seems to be an interesting premise.

Basically - it looks like it's the foundation of ketosis but you’re allowed to eat carbs after you work out and not during the day. I can't find many sources on this and I'm wondering if it would be considered more "bro-science" or if this is accepted as scientifically sound in the greater fitness community (something I'm usnure of since I've not heard of it until now)?

Comment: Look in the back of the Carb Backloading book. There is a substantial references section. If you're concerned about if eating 400g of simple carbs each night is healthy, I'd recommend getting a lipid/glucose panel done on the final morning of your 10-day keto (you can often do these dirt cheap at a hospital, just call their lab and ask how much a self-ordered lipid/glucose panel costs), and then do another after a month on the CBL and see if your numbers are clean. I haven't heard of anyone coming back with bad numbers, but it's worth monitoring anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robb Wolf, one of the most famous people in the paleo community, who is pretty legitimate as a science guy, had Kiefer on his podcast, which is free to listen to on the website.  I think that's a great endorsement for Kiefer.  Oh also:

Kiefer graduated Magna Cum Laude with a Bachelor’s in Mathematics and a Bachelor’s in Physics in three years then became a Ph.D. candidate in physics at the University of Florida in only a year.

In the end, it's all about trying it and see how it works for you.  Although one proviso is that it doesn't work as well if your body fat percentage is above 20%.  He recommends Carb Nite, something else he came up with years ago, as a better program.

Comment: Wolf has the palmares, but how does a PhD in physics qualify Kiefer? And I'm skeptical on any diet that "works" according to different body fat percentages. (I'm skeptical on Paleo/atkins/etc as well, but that's a different issue.)